# Literal representation of 0.3 in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, floating-point, ieee-754

If I type `0.3` into the Chrome console it prints `0.3` back at me.

Is this basically saying: "you typed in a Number literal with the contents `0.3`, and I replay that representation back to you in the console as a convenience, even though under the hood and in reality it cannot be exactly represented and the best approximation I can come up with is `0.30000000000000004`"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the [internal representation](http://www.exploringbinary.com/floating-point-converter/) is

0.299999999999999988897769753748434595763683319091796875

It could have printed 0.29999999999999999, which is the internal value rounded to 17 significant digits. Rounding to [17 digits is the conservative way to preserve any internal value](http://www.exploringbinary.com/number-of-digits-required-for-round-trip-conversions/). But in this case 0.3 works just as well (after all, that is what you started with), and since it's shorter that is what is printed.

So it didn't take your string input and echo it back -- it just worked out that way (as it would for any input of 15 significant digits or less).

Comment: And `0.1+0.2` gives `0.30000000000000004` because the errors in representation of `0.1` and `0.2` combine to give a result that when rounded to 17 significant digits is `0.30000000000000004`.

Comment: @BenAston: Yes. [There's no shorter string that can recreate that double-precision value](http://www.exploringbinary.com/java-doesnt-print-the-shortest-strings-that-round-trip/).